# How does create-react-app re-use an existing Browser tab after running `npm run start`?

Tags: javascript, applescript

Running `open http://localhost:8080` in Terminal will open a new tab each time.

How does create-react-app re-use an existing Browser tab, when available?

## *Update*

It looks like [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-dev-utils/openBrowser.js#L64) is the place where the magic happens:

```
function startBrowserProcess(browser, url) {
  // If we're on OS X, the user hasn't specifically
  // requested a different browser, we can try opening
  // Chrome with AppleScript. This lets us reuse an
  // existing tab when possible instead of creating a new one.
  const shouldTryOpenChromeWithAppleScript =
    process.platform === 'darwin' &&
    (typeof browser !== 'string' || browser === OSX_CHROME);

  if (shouldTryOpenChromeWithAppleScript) {
    try {
      // Try our best to reuse existing tab
      // on OS X Google Chrome with AppleScript
      execSync('ps cax | grep "Google Chrome"');
      execSync('osascript openChrome.applescript "' + encodeURI(url) + '"', {
        cwd: __dirname,
        stdio: 'ignore',
      });
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      // Ignore errors.
    }
  }

  // Another special case: on OS X, check if BROWSER has been set to "open".
  // In this case, instead of passing `open` to `opn` (which won't work),
  // just ignore it (thus ensuring the intended behavior, i.e. opening the system browser):
  // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1690#issuecomment-283518768
  if (process.platform === 'darwin' && browser === 'open') {
    browser = undefined;
  }

  // Fallback to opn
  // (It will always open new tab)
  try {
    var options = { app: browser };
    opn(url, options).catch(() => {}); // Prevent `unhandledRejection` error.
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, I still don't know how this is working.  I am on OS X, and I do have the `osascript` binary, surprisingly. But I'm not sure how to use it within Terminal.

I've tried `osascript openChrome.applescript "localhost:8080"`, but I'm getting the following error:

`osascript: openChrome.applescript: No such file or directory`

What is the proper use of the `osascript` command to open `http://localhost:8080` in the current tab, if it exists?

## *Update*

It looks like the openChrome.applescript file [is somewhere included within create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/e9abde739240b3124ab7237cbf32a370c209511e/packages/react-dev-utils/package.json#L31), but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested `osascript /path/to/openChrome.applescript "http://localhost:8080"` and it works as expected.

If you don't have the **openChrome.applescript** *script*, then here its *source code URL*: [openChrome.applescript](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/e9abde739240b3124ab7237cbf32a370c209511e/packages/react-dev-utils/openChrome.applescript)